# angularjs show div if clicked inside a input field and hide if clicked outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I want to show my div if user clicks inside the input field, and if clicked outside only, then it should hide it. If clicked inside the field again, it shouldn't hide.
Here is my attempt:
**[JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/asmKj/1348/)**

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="HelpCtrl">
    <input type="text" id="myText" name="myText" ng-click="showHelp = ! showHelp">
    
    <div  class="details" ng-class="{ 'hidden': ! showHelp }">
    <p>
    The help text here!
    </p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

the problem is that when the page is opened, I see the help text, and it suddenly disappears and when I click inside the field, it shows again, but it disappears only when clicked inside the field again. Now I want it to hide only if clicked outside the field.
Please help me with this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use **ng-focus** instead of ng-click

[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/docikiyRlYNOu5OGb1PE?p=preview)

```
<input type="text" ng-focus="focused = true" ng-blur="focused = false" />
<p ng-if="focused">Input has focus!</p>
```

Comment: why does it take a second more in mine to hide the element? in your plunker it is immediate effect. How can I also modify the css transitions? now that you have removed the ng-class?

Comment: @JeevaArulanandam It won't work with `ng-class="{'hidden':!focused}"`

Comment: I think you forget to add  `.hidden{display:none;}`  in your css file

Answer (score 1):

below code should help you.

```
<style>

.hidden{
 -webkit-transition: width 2s; transition: width 2s;
 display:none !important;;

}
.details{
display:block;
}
</style>
    <div ng-app="app">
     <div ng-controller="HelpCtrl">
              <input type="text" id="myText" name="myText" ng-focus="showHelp = true" ng-blur="showHelp = false">

    <div  class="details" ng-class="{'hidden':!showHelp}">
    <p>
    The help text here!
    </p>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: good, but i want to be able to add css transitions when it shows/hides. That is why i used ng-class. And with your solution the ng-blur takes a few seconds to hide it... which is a bit annoying.